# DBIx::Class base result class

Tags: mysql, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I am trying to create a model for Catalyst by using DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader. I want the result classes to have a base class I can add methods to. So MyTable.pm inherits from Base.pm which inherits from DBIx::Class::core (default).

Somehow I cannot figure out how to do this. my create script is below, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? The script creates my model ok, but all resultset classes just directly inherit from DBIx::Class::core without my Base class in between.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw/ make_schema_at /;

#specifically for the entities many-2-many relation
$ENV{DBIC_OVERWRITE_HELPER_METHODS_OK} = 1;

make_schema_at(
    'MyApp::Schema',
    { 
        dump_directory          => '/tmp',
        debug                   => 1, 
        overwrite_modifications => 1, 
        components              => ['EncodedColumn'],  #encoded password column
        use_namespaces          => 1,
        default_resultset_class => 'Base'

    },
    [ 'DBI:mysql:database=mydb;host=localhost;port=3306','rob', '******' ],
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just want to add in `result_base_class` (and probably drop the `default_resultset_class`)–

```
env DBIC_OVERWRITE_HELPER_METHODS_OK=1 \
   dbicdump \
   -o result_base_class="FullNameOf::Base" \
   -o debug=1 \
   -o dump_directory=./tmp \
   -o components='["EncodedColumn"]' \
   -o use_namespaces=1 \
   -o overwrite_modifications=1 \
   "DBI:mysql:database=mydb;host=localhost;port=3306" \
   rob "******"
```

Update, relevant doc: [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#result_base_class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader%3a%3aBase#result_base_class).

Comment: Hi Asley,thanks for the answer, I tried it but the base class still remains the same, ie no inheritance of my base class: 

package K2P::Schema::Result::ProductStore;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';

__PACKAGE__->load_components("EncodedColumn");

...

Comment: @Rob: this does work so perhaps it’s because it’s not overwriting it? Try it in a new empty dir (remove -o overwrite_modifications=1) and see what happens. Upgrade all your DBIx:: space?